# dd is crashing after a few hours of transfer

Tags: osx, dd, macintosh

I am trying to clone a external hardrive ( 1.5T ) to a second one ( 3T ) with dd. I am working on Unix and want to create a disk image.

Here is the command I am using :

```
dd if=/dev/disk1 of=/Volumes/FreeAgent\ GoFlex\ Drive\ DENISE/SeaGate_AC.dmg conv=noerror
```

I have used the following command to check the progress of my transfer:

```
kill -INFO 1880
```

At the beginning it was working correctly and here is an example of the output:

```
8576952+0 records in
8576952+0 records out
4391399424 bytes transferred in 658.085533 secs (6672992 bytes/sec)
```

But after a while, the terminal is not answering and even my Finder is crashing when I am trying to access the destination HD.

I have tried with the option sync with the same result

Any suggestions are welcome...

Thanks 
Simon

Here is the output of dmesg as suggested by slm:

```
2Request - begin
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5: GetBufferDescriptor with buffer=0 dataSize=0 task=0
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - SCSITaskStatus 2
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - SendCommand non-zero status,     check condition
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - senseSize 18, respCode 0x72,    senseKey 0x1, addlSenseCode 0x0, addlSenseQual 0x1d, addlLength 0xe
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - returning main line 0
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x12f7ed00]::externalMethod(2, 0x1102c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x12f7ed00]::externalMethod(9, 0x1102c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12)::UpdateSelfTestResults: using     IssueSmartDiagnosticStatus
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - begin
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5: GetBufferDescriptor with buffer=12ee1928 dataSize=200 task=0
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - SCSITaskStatus 0
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - returning main line 1
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x12f7ed00]::externalMethod(2, 0x1102c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x12f7ed00]::externalMethod(10, 0x1102c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x12f7ed00]::externalMethod(1, 0x1102c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x9ffc000]::externalMethod(0, 0x1102c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x9ffc000]::externalMethod(23, 0x1102c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x9ffc000]::externalMethod(1, 0x1102c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x9ffc000]::externalMethod(0, 0x1152c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x9ffc000]::externalMethod(24, 0x1442c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0x9ffc000]::externalMethod(1, 0x1442c70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0xa014600]::externalMethod(0, 0x112ac70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0xa014600]::externalMethod(2, 0x112ac70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0xa014600]::externalMethod(12, 0x112ac70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12)::IssueSmartRequest: using IssueSmartReturnStatus
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - begin
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5: GetBufferDescriptor with buffer=0 dataSize=0 task=0
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - SCSITaskStatus 2
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - SendCommand non-zero status,  check condition
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - senseSize 18, respCode 0x72,     senseKey 0x1, addlSenseCode 0x0, addlSenseQual 0x1d, addlLength 0xe
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - returning main line 0
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0xa014600]::externalMethod(2, 0x112ac70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0xa014600]::externalMethod(9, 0x112ac70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12)::UpdateSelfTestResults: using IssueSmartDiagnosticStatus
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - begin
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5: GetBufferDescriptor with buffer=12ee1928 dataSize=200 task=0
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - SCSITaskStatus 0
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueSAT12Request - returning main line 1
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0xa014600]::externalMethod(2, 0x112ac70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0xa014600]::externalMethod(10, 0x112ac70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSecUserClient00_10_5[0xa014600]::externalMethod(1, 0x112ac70, 0, 0, 0)
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12) handling stop request
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12) IssueModeSelectTimer: shortTime = 1
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12)::SetModeSelectTimer: using shortime
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12) IssueModeSelectTimer: complete
com_seagate_IOPowSec00_10_5-(NA0LVZ12): IssueStopUnderDeviceControlCommand
Warning: audit space low (< 5% free)on audit log file-system
```

My image file is about 17G...

**UPDATE #1**

Both drives are formatted as `NTFS`. The system they're mounted on is `Mac OSX 10.6.8`. The `GoFlex` software provided by Seagate is being used to access the 3TB drive.

The 1.5TB HDD is failing and during boot up `Disk Utility` is failing when scanning the drive.

Comment: My system is 64 bits; For dmesg see below; and I am cloning the 1.5 T to a disk image, thus the way I understand, it's going to be a file of 1.5 T on my 3 T... Correct ?

Comment: Nope, the 3T is not partitioned.

Comment: THis is OS X 10.6.8

Comment: What do you mean a filesystem ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6877/discussion-between-slm-and-simon)

Comment: After further discussions with @Simon, I suggested a couple of options, given 1.5TB HDD is failing and is NTFS, try running chkdsk on windows system, also running ddrescue instead of dd. Awaiting an update from OP before continuing any further triage.

Comment: Just a little update for those who might run in the same problem. I was able to clone the 1.5T to an external HDD by just uninstalling and removing any software/crap Seagate is installing when you buy their HDD. It's probably the source of all my worries too. I haven't try yet to run chkdsk on windows, I will keep you updated.

Comment: A co-worker attempted to use that same crapware. We told him to just use clonezilla.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you're trying to write a [master boot record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) formatted drive, and `MBR` can only support up to **2TB**.

You're going to have to format your **3TB** drive using a [GUID Partitioning Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)  layout. I would suggest partitioning the 3TB drive using [parted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parted) and then using [clonezilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla) to copy the **2TB** drive's data to the **3TB** drive.

Comment: While this is true, the drive he is attempting to "clone" is less than 2TB.

Comment: If you notice where it's dying, it's roughly at the 2^32 (4391399424) border.